# TensorFlow Segmentor

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation

I've written the following [segmentor](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Mnfrcu5AU47rRoPwweQv8kRGzTPJaXwJf7zd3pksXK4/edit?usp=sharing) and I can't get the accuracy to work. In fact I'm always getting accuracy of 0.0 whatever the size of my sample.

I think the problem is at the sigmoid layer at the end of U() function where a tensor of continuous elements between 0 and 1 (conv10) is further compared to a binary tensor and therefore there's no chance of getting any equality between the two.

UPDATE: The code can be found as git [here](https://gist.github.com/JulienBelanger/800972a626898b8a2f1ee24765692c62)

Comment: I see you used Google Docs to share the code. I think something like gist.github.com would be easier to read

Comment: Git is given, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've resolve the issue. The problem was the numpy arrays conversion to placeholder at feed level. The new update code as git can be found at : https://github.com/JulienBelanger/TensorFlow-Image-Segmentation